# Difference between selecting multiple tables with JOIN and plain select

Tags: sql, sql-server

How does SQL Server execute these two queries, is there any difference:

1. Select with join

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM AspNetUsers
   LEFT JOIN AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetUserRoles.UserId
   LEFT JOIN AspNetRoles ON AspNetUserRoles.RoleId = AspNetRoles.Id
   ```
2. Select without join

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles
   WHERE AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetUserRoles.UserId 
     AND AspNetUserRoles.RoleId = AspNetRoles.Id
   ```

The results I get are the same, except the order of columns.

Comment: Yes.  The two are semantically different.  The first does outer joins and the second inner joins.  The first is correct syntactically.  The second uses an archaic form of the `join` syntax which, for historical reasons, SQL parsers still accept.

Comment: Ggordon is entirely correct but I'll add the note that inner joins and outer joins can have identical results even though semantically different queries. In your case with your data that's apparently true and would imply then that every user has at least one role. Add a user without a role and then compare again.

Comment: The result is the same - however, query #1 is the **preferred** way of doing it - it uses the ANSI/ISO standard JOIN syntax, and it's clearer. Query #2 is the old, deprecated style of doing JOIN's which was replaced by the ANSI/ISO standard JOIN syntax in the **SQL-92** standard in **1992** - about time to stop using that old syntax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the SQL Server "Actual Execution Plan" (press down the Actual Execution Plan button in the SQL Server Management Studio) to help you find the difference of how SQL Server will do to execute them.

If it is "INNER JOIN" VS "Without JOIN" then the SQL Server will be smart enough to make them identical.

but "LEFT JOIN" VS "Without JOIN" has different results and also has different EXECUTION PLAN

Check the attached photo[image]:

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SQL Server but I don't think it works[1] differently from other DBMS for fundamental aspects of SQL such as those involved in your question.
Though note that my answer is based on only *general* SQL experience (such as dBase, Informix, Paradox, Oracle, and obviously MySQL)

That said, I don't expect a different behaviour between your two versions, because you only use `LEFT JOIN`s and simple `ON` conditions, so its absolutely equivalent to using the `WHERE` approach.

Nevertheless I'm surprised you report that only *the order* of columns differ. In fact, in your #1 version you'd get only those of the `AspNetUsers` table, while #2 should return *all* columns of *all* tables.

[1] Added after reading the @Atheer Mostafa's answer: more precisely, SQL Server may *internally work* differently, but the results should be the same.